# How to read and understand CPU specs?

Tags: cpu, computer-building

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read Intel CPU specs?](https://superuser.com/questions/225915/how-do-i-read-intel-cpu-specs)

So I'm building myself a computer, and I know all the components and where they go, but I have no idea how to read and compare CPU specifications, such as how to tell the difference between different models.

Where do I begin if I want to understand those?

Comment: I think that due to "... and compare" part this question is not a duplicate. E.g. which CPU is faster: one with a higher GHz or one with a bigger cache, etc.

Comment: @Tom I would agree with haimg that this is **not a dupe**. This is more about understanding the specs rather than just finding them.

Comment: @haimg: Comparison is trivial once you understand them, and that's what the other question already helps you doing. The other question does help you understand the specs (and isn't about finding them).

Comment: (cc @BloodPhilia)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to look for CPU specs: [CPU-World](http://www.cpu-world.com/sspec/index.html)

You need to find the specific CPU type looking at the CPU's manual or on the CPU itself
(Before connecting the CPU fan).

For example, check this picture of CPU from Wikipedia: [image: Top view of an Intel central processing unit Core i7 Sandy Bridge type core, model 2600K. LGA 1155 socket, 32 nm process, core frequency 3.40 GHz, By Eric Gaba.]
You can see this CPU's spec here: [CPU-World - Intel i7 - 2600k 3.40GHZ](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i7/Intel-Core%20i7-2600K%20CM8062300833908.html)

Just search for the model in the site.

If you want to compare performance of different CPUs, try [Tom's hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/), they are the best at comparisons and reviews.

EDIT:
I thought you wanted to know where to see and compare the specifications of different CPUs, If you want to learn details about what each specification means, you can check this out:

[Hardware-Revolution - 12 CPU Specifications Explained in Plain English](http://www.hardware-revolution.com/12-cpu-specifications-explained-in-plain-english/)

You are welcome to ask for more details if you want.

Answer (score -1):

If it's an Intel chip you can use their [Product information website](http://ark.intel.com/). It also contains descriptions of the various model features, such as virtualization technology, AES instruction, etc.

(Too many variants, if you ask me)